# Cannot find Keystore Entry. But I know it's there

Tags: android, gradle, keystore

Android Studio on Windows 10

cannot load key store: unrecognized keystore entry

I have an existing app compiled and signed.  I've created a new version of it.  The unique id for the app is the same (com.name.appname).  I want to sign the new version with the existing key.
I have the key.  I know the password.  I know the alias is correct.  All I get back is:
**cannot load key store: unrecognized keystore entry**

More specifially:  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key [name] from store "[path]\publishKey": Unrecognized keystore entry

All of the answers I see here are along the lines of "use the command line utility to find the key alias", bla bla bla...

I know this stuff is there and correct.  It's just not letting me use it.

What am I missing here?  Is there something I need to edit to let it know that I indeed DO want to use that signature?

Comment: can you browse your alias name while generating apk?

Comment: You would think that clicking the little button with the "..." on it would bring up a browse dialog.  But, no.  Even there it gives me the same error.

Comment: this happens if you entered wrong keystore password or if keystore is tampered

Comment: make sure you are using correct keystore file

Comment: No - the password is correct.  It IS the correct keystore file.  Plus, I can open the file with a KeyStore viewer.  I can see my entries.  I can edit them.  And in fact on ONE machine I can use the file.  It's when I use the exact file on a different machine it's a problem.  I'm trying to move my stuff to a new development environment.  I do NOT want to lose all my keys in the process

Comment: I found a solution.  I will add an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that somehow, someway, the keystore file got corrupted.  Perhaps one of the later entries did it.  I do not know.
But the way I got around this was by using a KeyStore Explorer, I was able to save the file from there, and remove the last couple of entries.

I was then able to find the alias and sign my app normally.  Both from the old machine and the new one.

Just leaving this here in hopes that someone else will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command to list the content of your keystore file:

keytool -list -keystore .keystore

If you are looking for a specific alias, you can also specify it in the command:

keytool -list -keystore .keystore -alias foo

If the alias is not found, it will display an exception:

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias does not exis

// other wise you are used following command in command prompt:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe base64